# TSQL command to delete backup files older than N hours

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone please help me with a TSQL commmand to delete backup files older than N hours?

Comment: Please consider to show your effort.

Answer (score 7):

Remember that T-SQL should not be used to do file maintenance. Instead you should use Powershell to delete /move / copy etc files.

**Tsql way:**

use `xp_cmdshell` command along with the `FORFILES` command

e.g Delete all .sql files in the C:\Backup directory and its subfolders where the file modified date is more than 30 days old.

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'FORFILES /p c:\BACKUP /s /m *.sql /d -30 /c "CMD /C del /Q /F @FILE"'
```

***Disclaimer***: *Enabling xp_cmdshell is a security risk and not many companies allow it.*

[**Powershell Way**](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/10/31/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-delete-all-the-files-in-a-folder-older-than-90-days.aspx) --> This should be the right approach !!

A full script can be found at [technet](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Delete-files-older-than-x-13b29c09#content).

```
## Delete files older than 90 days

$a = Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts
foreach($x in $a)
    {
        $y = ((Get-Date) - $x.CreationTime).Days
        if ($y -gt 90 -and $x.PsISContainer -ne $True)
            {$x.Delete()}
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove files pragmatically you could use the `master.dbo.xp_delete_file` extended stored procedure but it is not generally recommended to use this as these types of procedure are scheduled to be removed in a future version of SQL Server although I'm not sure when that will be.

If this is something that could possibly be in place for a long time after deployment I would recommend you use a `maintenance plan` as this functionality is built in.

Comment: If you want to do this through T-SQL, the xp_delete_file is your best option. As @JamesAnderson says, it's undocumented, but I have not seen any issues with it since the early releases of SQL Server 2005. Review my article if you would like to see the details.

http://www.patrickkeisler.com/2012/11/how-to-use-xpdeletefile-to-purge-old.html

Answer (score 2):

Below is the T-SQL to delete old backups from a location having age as N:

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_delete_file    
    0,
    N'**FILEPATH OF OLD BACKUPS LOCATION**',
    N'bak',
    N'**DATE BEFORE WHICH YOU DONT WANT TO KEEP BACKUPS** T **TIME**',
    1 ;
```