# How to grant xp_delete_file to non-sysadmin login?

Tags: sql-server-2014, backup, ssms, delete, storage

I want to delete old backups from shared folder, which are located on separate NAS storage, using newly created SQL login. Is there any workaround to execute xp_delete_file using another account which is not a member of sysadmin role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting files on NAS should not be done by sql server. You should [rather use powershell](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/64938/8783) to do it.

You can use my function [Clean-NASOldFiles](https://gist.github.com/TheRockStarDBA/36fbac1eaec40b25584362824fcc91e4) which uses robocopy to scan files extremely fast and will then delete based on your input.